# How to install PrettyFaces for Jakarta Faces 4.x

Tags: jsf, prettyfaces, jakarta-migration

I am using pretty faces in Jakarta Server Faces app. My POM is having following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
        <artifactId>rewrite-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
        <artifactId>rewrite-config-prettyfaces</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.ocpsoft</groupId>
       <artifactId>prettyfaces-jsf2</artifactId>
       <version>3.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

First I tried with two rewrite dependencies and then tried with last one prettyfaces dependency but no one worked. All three also didn't work.
It is always failing to deploy on Wildfly 30 giving following errors:

```
22:01:42,194 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (MSC service thread 1-8) Failed to define class com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyViewHandler in Module "deployment.camplus.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/ocpsoft/pretty/faces/application/PrettyViewHandler
```

Not only this one error. It is giving following errors as well along with it

```
22:01:42,121 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (MSC service thread 1-8) Failed to define class com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyNavigationHandler in Module "deployment.camplus.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/ocpsoft/pretty/faces/application/PrettyNavigationHandler

22:01:42,111 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (MSC service thread 1-8) Failed to define class org.ocpsoft.rewrite.faces.RewriteViewHandler in Module "deployment.camplus.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/ocpsoft/rewrite/faces/RewriteViewHandler
```

I have also tried by adding following in the web.xml

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

And my pretty-config.xml file is:

```
<pretty-config
    xmlns="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces
                      http://ocpsoft.org/xml/ns/prettyfaces/rewrite-config-prettyfaces.xsd">

    <url-mapping id="login">
        <pattern value="/login" />
        <view-id value="/Login.jsf" />
    </url-mapping>
</pretty-config>
```

Tried everything written on the website but pretty faces are not working and also failing on deployment on Wildfly30.

Jakarta version is 10 and Java version is 21

Comment: Your question is confusing. Firstly, WildFly 21 is not a Jakarta EE 10 server and secondly, the pom.xml doesn't match their own installation guide at https://www.ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/

Comment: thanks for the correction. Wildfly is 30 and for the pretty faces, I have added three libraries, and mentioned that I tried prettyfaes library separately and two rewrite libraries separately as well.

Comment: Documentation says that you should then be using rewrite version 10.x (and NOT prettyfaces-jsf2 because that's clearly for JSF 2.x while you're using Faces 4.x). Give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolve by using following two dependencies only

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
        <artifactId>rewrite-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
        <artifactId>rewrite-config-prettyfaces</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also the mentioned filter should not be there in web.xml